# Eduardo's Krazy English Kwiz

Tags: word, wordplay, word-property, english, odd-one-out

Eduardo is having a dream the night before his English quiz. Actually it's a nightmare. His teacher hands him the quiz and says "Hello, Eduardo. To wake up confident and rested, just answer this *three-part question* correctly." Eduardo reads over the quiz and is puzzled, angry, frustrated, and *very, very* tired, but he sees no way out of his dream other than acing the quiz.

QUESTION: Your three-letter "Dream Word" is _ _ _ and the two clues hidden in this puzzle are ___ and ___ **.**

CLUES:

1. One letter of the Dream Word is the letter *preceding* the letter with the optional accent in a [vocabulary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocabulary%20entry) that ends with an apostrophe.
2. Another letter of the Dream Word is the first letter of the first name of the author of an American and British bestseller, written in English. It was first published (intentionally) in a foreign-language translation about a month before it came out in English.
3. Another letter of the Dream Word is the first letter of the strange odd-man-out among these pairs:

> adapt/adaptive, abuse/abusive, conduct/conductive,
> convulse/convulsive, corrode/corrosive, corrupt/corruptive,
> deceive/deceptive, elude/elusive, expend/expensive,
> explode/explosive, induct/inductive, misuse/misusive,
> protect/protective, reduce/reductive, repulse/repulsive

4. Each of the two hidden clues is a single word. Together, they will confirm that your Dream Word is correct.

### Additional Clues

The following hints are not strictly required to solve the puzzle but were added to aid in the process.

**5. Additional clue:**

> The first letter of the (English) name of the foreign language in Clue (2) is, by coincidence, the same as the first letter of the author's first name, and this is *not* a Romance language.

**6. Additional clue:**

> About Clue (3): <s>30</s> 29

**7. Additional clue:**

> The vocabulary entry in Clue (1) is a noun.

**8. Additional clue*s*:**

> The book title in Clue (2) is that of another work, which is central to the book's plot.

**9. Additional clue:**

> If you count *only* the letters in the answer to clue (1), they total seven. Each is different from the others and, by coincidence, the last letter is the same letter as in  Clue (5).

**10. Additional clue:**

> The optional accent in Clue (1) is one you know, but *not* a diaeresis (umlaut), grave accent, acute accent, tilde, overring, or cedilla.

**11. Additional clue:**

> Eduardo has just turned in his quiz and reports that his Dream Word can be anagrammed to only one other English word.

**12. Additional clue:**

> Don't just stare at Clue (3); do some work!

**13. Additional clue:**

> The first word in the title of the translated book in Clue (2) is an anagram of the first word in the English title.

**14. Additional clue:**

> A little birdie gave Eduardo a big hint: The first word of the book title is *The.*

**15. Final additional clue:**

> Clue (14) is actually two clues about the book title.

Comment: Should we or should we not be assuming that the three letters of the Dream Word are given _in order_ by 1,2,3? (My current assumption is that we should not.)

Comment: Incidentally, in your previous question I had a vocabulary-entry-ending-in-apostrophe that doesn't have any letter with an optional accent...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan (1) The clues make no mention of order and refer to "one/another letter," so they may or may not be in order; (2) Let's wait until there is a correct answer to learn your word, just in case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Final Answer: MAD with in-question clues "angry" and "Krazy". Maître d' for the vocabulary entry gives A. "The Goldfinch" or "Het puttertje" by Donna Tartt, first published in Dutch, gives D. And misusive is the only non-word in the list, which gives M.

Comment: @DjinTonic It might actually be more helpful to say how much JM has got *right* here. If an answer is expected to have *all* parts correct before you will confirm it is so, this puzzle could end up putting people off answering or attracting a series of partially-correct-but-not-known-to-be-so answers, neither of which is ideal.

Comment: Could the second clue word (instead of rot13(sehfgengrq) be rot13(fgenatr) instead? As being somewhat related to the other definition of your word?)

Comment: @El-Guest I will  only reiterate that Clue (4) refers to two different words, which, taken together, should give you great confidence that your Dream Word is correct. P.S. I'm new here -- can you please explain the rot... part? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks djintonic, I deleted the comment

Comment: @Stiv I will check the first answer that has all three parts of the Quiz Question correct, and award the bounty to the answer that has the Quiz Question correct and the most correct answers for Clues 1-3. I'll post a complete answer after the bounty is up.

Comment: @JonathanMichala has 2 out of 3 correct in the Quiz Question and 2 out of 3 correct for Clues 1-3.

Comment: Now updated my answer after the final clue

Comment: @JonathanMichala I was pretty sure the last clue would do the trick, which is why I labeled it Final Clue :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the answers to Clues 1-4, followed by the answer to Eduardo's quiz question:**

Answer to Clue 1:

> **[maître d'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maitre%20d%27)** or **maitre d'** (n. plural maître d's or maitre d's), short for [maître d'hôtel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ma%C3%AEtre%20d%27h%C3%B4tel).
>
>  I used *vocabulary entry* in the clue rather than *word* to avoid
>  any ambiguity about the meaning and to suggest that the
>  answer might *not* be a single word in the usual sense.

Answer to Clue 2:

> **Donna Tartt's** novel *[The Goldfinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goldfinch_(novel))* was published in 2013 and won the 2014 Pulitzer Prize for literature. The title is the name of a 1654
>  [painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goldfinch_(painting)) by the Dutch artist Carel Fabritius that figures
>  predominantly in the plot. In homage to this Dutch connection and
>  probably as a means of generating prepublication reviews and
>  anticipation, the Dutch translation was released [a month before](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/1my9ai/donna_tartts_the_goldfinch_released_in_the/)
>  the novel came out in English.

Answer to Clue 3:

> At first blush there appear to be 30 words arranged in 15
>  verb/adjective pairs. However, you can make a good case that there are only 29 because **misusive**
>  isn't a bona fide word at all. It occurs very rarely in print and you won't find
>  it in your dictionary or mine.
>  (Try thinking of a definition and an illustrative example sentence
>  before checking out the print [examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572424/what-is-the-corresponding-adjective-derived-from-the-verb-misuse) I did manage to find.)
>  Regardless of one's opinion about the legitimacy of *misusive,* being
>  ignored by dictionaries and writers makes this pair the odd man out.

Answer to Clue 4:

> Only two combinations of the three letters in the Dream Word are words.
>  The puzzle contains hints for two different meanings of one of the words: **Krazy** and **angry**.

Eduardo woke up as promised after he turned in this correct answer to his Quiz Question:

> Your three-letter "Dream Word" is **[mad](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad)** and the two clues hidden in
>  this puzzle are **Krazy** and **angry**. Also see [ref](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/can-mad-mean-angry#:%7E:text=We%20may%20never%20know.,meaning%20has%20often%20been%20criticized.).